# How can I delete an existing path alias?

Tags: 9, path-aliases

In Drupal 7, a path alias can be deleted with code similar to the following one.

```php
path_delete(array('source' => "problem/{$problem->nid}/{$problem_src->nid}"));
```

How can I delete path aliases in Drupal 9?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete path alias: Drupal(8/9/10)

```
$path_alias_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('path_alias');
// Load path alias by path
$alias_objects = $path_alias_manager->loadByProperties([
  'path' => '/node/' . $nid
]);
foreach ($alias_objects as $alias_object) {
  // Delete the path alias
  $alias_object->delete();
}
```

Note: Drupal(8/9/10) **"path"** field column maintained instead of **"source"** column